# Платформа для настольных приложений на Java

Tags: java, framework

Изучаю Java для реализации долгосрочного проекта. При создании проекта настольного приложения на NetBeans есть предупреждение о том, что Swing не будет дорабатываться.
Значит ли это, что новые проекты на Swing начинать не стоит?
Какую лучше платформу выбрать для настольных приложений?
Особенности использования этих платформ на NetBeans и IDEA (или в других)?

Comment: Дополнение к вопросу: "[Стоит ли использовать Spring MVC]( http://hashcode.ru/questions/31215/%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-spring-mvc)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Долгое время занимался разработкой клиентских приложений на Swing (b2b клиенты и пр.) и пришел к такому выводу:

- Для корпоративных приложений (клиент
     банки, b2b) связка Java+Swing
     годится, когда на бекенде у
     приложения java сервер.
- Для настольных GUI приложений java это зло.

К примеру такие классные апликухи как azureus или personalbrain убивают своей монструозностью. То есть легкое десктопное приложение на джаве не получить.

Я пока для себя остановился на wxpython+python для более менее больших приложений где много гуя и чистый wxwidgets+c++ для апликух по меньше, где важна легковесность.

> Особенности использования этих
> платформ на NetBeans и IDEA (или в
> других)?

Netbeans со своим визуальным редактором хорош для визуального проектирования, мышкой накидал форму и закодил функционал, но для серьезных проектов эффективнее гуй писать вручную, а там уже любая ide подойдет.

Comment: >> Для корпоративных приложений (клиент банки, b2b) связка Java+Swing годится, когда на бекенде у приложения java сервер <br />

А при чём тут Swing? Если проблема с интеграцией с какой-то конкретной технологией, то Swing тогда ни при чём.

Comment: Я наверное просто неясно выразил мысль, проблема не в интеграции. Я имею ввиду что в корпоративном секторе если пишется некая система с гуевым клиентом на java то все в рамках стека технологий и то сколько памяти ест клиентская программа особо не важно, главное чтобы все четко работало.
а для обычных десктопных приложений на массового пользователя это не годится.

Answer (score 2):

Создано замечательное решение для создания оконных приложений: **JavaFX**. Там все настолько упрощено, что и работать с ней приятно. Тем более `NetBeans` имеет плагины для графического построения дизайна приложений на **JavaFX**.

Comment: Согласен с вами, но про него читал, что графика приложений на JavaFX тормозит

Comment: Ну, если вы пишете для старых компьютеров. На современных не замечал. Тем не менее, мне так кажется, что Оракл если создало такую новую платформу, то и продвигать ее далее будет.

Comment: Хорошо, рассмотрим как вариант.

Answer (score 0):

Не значит!!! Будьте спокойны! Здесь имелось ввиду Платформа приложений Swing(JSR-296) — не Swing, библиотека для создания графического интерфейса на языке Java.

Comment: А новые приложения будут иметь другую платформу, отличную от JSR-296?  
Не могли бы более подробно разьяснить.

Comment: SAF (Swing Application Framework) это просто фреймворк на основе свинга, но не сам свинг.
Если интересует вся история с SAF, подробности можете почитать здесь http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/java/71561/
Но за свинг не беспокойтесь, он никуда не денется :)